# Uploading 100s of images from Android Tablet using C# web application

Tags: c#, android, image, tablet

I'm sure I'll have plenty of questions concerning this new project.

I'd like to create a web application that will give a user the ability to select say 100+ photos from an Android tablet photo gallery.  I want them to be able to start the upload and if they leave the application and come back be able to start where they left off.  For instance, select images, click submit, upload 10 out of 100 images, log off, log back in, and start uploading the rest of the images.

Is there a way to do this?

The things I'm not sure about is the location of the images on the Android tablet, whether the images saved on the Android is always in the same location, whether I can access the images without some sort of post (the returning to the upload page after leaving).

Do you have any experience with this or any suggestions?